# Tabular with arrows or lines between some cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have a table like the one below and want to write this in Latex. what would be the best aproach? I have tried it with Tikz where i can nest a Table but failed with the lines wich connect the different fields. Another solution would be to use a tikz tree, but there i don't know how to label the edges.

Is it possible to create something like this with an easy markup, either in TikZ or with any other latex package?

[image: Huffman Coding]

Comment: Look more like a diagram or complex tree structure than as a table with some arrows. Search in tree tags (tikz-trees, tikz-qtree ...)  to see some examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a beginning of a solution with tikz matrix[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[every node/.style={minimum height=2em}]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes](Mat)
{
x_i  &|[minimum width=4em]|& P(x_i) &|[minimum width=4em]| Code &       &|[minimum width=4em]|      &       &|[minimum width=4em]|  &   &|[minimum width=4em]|  &   &\\
x_1 &&0.30     &        & 0.30  &   &0.30   &   &0.45&  &0.55&\\
x_2 && 0.25    &        & 0.25  &   &0.25   &   &0.30&  &0.45&\\
x_3 && 0.20   &     & 0.20  &   &0.25   &   &0.25&  &   &\\
x_4 && 0.12    &        &0.13   &   &0.20   &   &   &   &   &\\
x_5 && 0.08    &        &0.12   &   &       &   &   &   &   &\\
x_6 && 0.05    &        &   &   &       &   &   &   &   &\\
};

\draw (Mat-2-3.east) -- (Mat-2-3-|Mat-2-5.west)node[above,midway]{00};
\draw(Mat-5-3.east) --++(1em,0) -- (Mat-6-5.west)node[above,pos=0.2]{101};
\draw (Mat-6-3.east)-|node[above,pos=0.4]{1000}++(2em,-1em) coordinate(aa) --++(1em,0) |- (Mat-5-5.west);
\draw (Mat-7-3.east)-|node[below,pos=0.4]{1001} (aa);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice, didn't know about the possibility of "adressing" the matrix cells like any other named node. But in the first line with **draw** you don't need to specify the anchor east and west. The following compiles exactly the same:
_\draw (Mat-2-3) -- (Mat-2-5)node[above,midway]{00};_