# TikZ - same label for every left/right edge

Tags: labels, tikz-qtree

Is there a way to give every edge on the left the same label up to a specific level (I don't want labels on my leaf nodes).

I want to build a Huffman-Code, so it would be nice to have every left edge labeled with a 0 and every right edge labeled with a 1. Is there a way to do this with options or automated?

Here is my tree; it's rather big und will only fit onto an A4 landscape page:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle},
    level distance=15mm,
    sibling distance=8mm,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=90mm}}
\Tree
[ .205
    \edge node[auto=right]{0};
    [ .82
        \edge node[auto=right]{0};
        [ .40
            \edge node[auto=right]{0}; 
            [ .20
                \edge node[auto=right]{0}; 
                [ .10
                    \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                    [ .5 <nl> ]
                    \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                    [ .5 I  ]
                ]
                \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                [ .10 l ]
            ]
            \edge node[auto=left]{1};
            [ .20 t ]
        ]
        \edge node[auto=right]{0};
        [ .42
            \edge node[auto=right]{0};
            [ .20
                \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                [ .10
                    \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                    [ .5 b ]
                    \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                    [ .5 d ]
                ]
                \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                [ .10 p ]
            ]
            \edge node[auto=left]{1};
            [ .22
                \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                [ .12
                    \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                    [ .5 k ]
                    \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                    [ .7 u  ]
                ]
                \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                [ .10 s ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    \edge node[auto=left]{1};
    [ .123
        \edge node[auto=right]{0};
        [ .53
            \edge node[auto=right]{0};
            [ .24
                \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                [ .12 i ]
                \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                [ .12 o  ]
            ]
            \edge node[auto=left]{1};
            [ .29 l ]
        ]
        \edge node[auto=left]{0};
        [ .70
            \edge node[auto=right]{0};
            [ .30
                \edge node[auto=right]{0};
                [ .15 a ]
                \edge node[auto=left]{1};
                [ .15 n ]
            ]
            \edge node[auto=left]{1};
            [ .40 <sp>  ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always better to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68127/tabular-with-arrows-or-lines-between-some-cells ? You can also try a work-around with graphviz if you feel this is easier. Afterwards you can convert it to TikZ.

Answer (score 7):

Here a solution with [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest).

It is also possible to let TeX add the values of the children so that one would only need to give the structure of the tree and the values of the second-last. But that needs to be worked out.

A few ideas on what is possible with `forest`: [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120605/16595), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136885/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{el style/.style={midway, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+1pt, auto=right}}
\forestset{angled/.style={
    content/.expanded={\noexpand\textless\forestov{content}\noexpand\textgreater}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={parent anchor=south},
  where n children={0}{tier=word}{
    if={n==1}{% n == 1 means first child
      edge label={node[el style]{0}}
    }{
      edge label={node[el style, swap]{1}}
    }
  }
%
[205 [ 82 [40 [20 [10 [5 [nl, angled] ]
                      [5 [I] ] ]
                  [10 [l ] ] ]
              [20 [t ] ] ]
          [42 [20 [10 [5 [b] ]
                      [5 [d] ] ]
                  [10 [p] ] ]
              [22 [12 [5 [k] ]
                      [7 [u] ] ]
                  [10 [s ] ] ] ] ]
     [123 [53 [24 [12 [i] ]
                  [12 [o] ] ]
              [29 [l ] ] ]
          [70 [30 [15 [a] ]
                  [15 [n] ] ]
              [40 [sp, angled] ] ] ] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]