# How to draw search space tree in a dynamic manner

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees

I am visualising the search space for a set of binary variables. 
I have done it for three variables before; and now I am extending it to six but seems a tedious work to do. Thus, I am wondering if there is any systematic/dynamic way to draw the search tree. For example, I just supply the number of variables and a tree would be drawn with dummy names. is such a tool exist?

Here is my code for the three binary variables.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,level/.style={sibling distance=40mm/#1},node distance=1cm]
\node [circle,draw] (root){$$}
    child {node (a)at (0,.5){$1$}
        child {node  (ab){$2$}
        child {node (abc){$3$}}
        child {node (abc2){$4$}}
        }
        child {node  (ab2){$5$}
            child {node (ab2c) at(0.3,0){$6$}}
            child {node (ab2c2){$7$}}
        }
    }
      child {node (a2)at (0,.5){$8$}
      child {node  (a2b){$9$}
                          child {node at (.2,0) (a2bc){$10$}}
            child {node at(-.2,0) (a2bc2){$11$}}
            }
        child {node  (a2b2){$12$}
                    child {node  (a2b2c){$13$}}
            child {node (a2b2c2){$14$}}
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{search space}
\label{search_space}
\end{figure}
```

which will draw this

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could translate your problem so that one could understand it without knowing about the topic. So, try to explain it in terms of a tree. How many levels? How many children per node? …? Looks like the `forest` package may be helpful, see [tag:forest].

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel If I understand the question, with n binary variables, the tree has n levels and 2^n leaves (each node has always two children).

Answer (score 5):

This answer includes a [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) implementation.

In a `forest` environment, we only need to add one root node with the `ary Tree` key. The three arguments are:

1. The value of the root (never shown, usually `0`).
2. The number of children per node (in your example `2`).
3. The highest level (in your example `3`); note that the root node is in level 0.

The `ary Tree` style automatically adds `#2` children (see `repeat` key) which all use the `ary Tree` option but with the value of their parent’s contant as first argument.

This is used in the `content` key to set the value of the node. The formula is:

```
<value of the parent node> + 1 + (<i> - 1) * <Sum>
```

Here, `<i>` is just an integer for the child (the first child is `<i> = 1`, the second has `<i> = 2` and so on). The `<sum>` is the sum of children and children’s children for a node of the current level. This sum is calculated for every needed level at the root node with the `ary Tree calc`. (There also exists a `\foreach`-less solution that uses a basic TeX loop and counters and doesn’t any global macros.)

The `aryTree` function that is defined via the `declare function` key is used to access this summed value using the already evaluated value of `level()` in a `\csname …\endcsname` construction.

I have added the option `calign=first` in the last example which in my opinion shows the algorithm of the tree a little better. (Don’t ask me why one needs an additional `delay` for every extra level.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
  declare function={aryTree(\aryLevel)=\csname aryTree@level@\aryLevel\endcsname;}}
\forestset{
  ary Tree node/.style={node options={align=center}},
  setup ary Tree nodes/.style 2 args={
    ary Tree node/.append style={node options={text width={width("#1")},#2}}},
  ary Tree root/.style={node options={circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1em}},
  ary Tree calc/.code 2 args={%
    \expandafter\def\csname aryTree@level@\the\numexpr#2+1\relax\endcsname{0}%
    \foreach \aryLevel in {#2,...,1}{%
      \pgfmathparse
      {(#1)^(#2-\aryLevel)+\csname aryTree@level@\the\numexpr\aryLevel+1\relax\endcsname}%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname aryTree@level@\aryLevel\endcsname\pgfmathresult}},
  ary Tree/.style n args={3}{% #1 = parent value, #2 = children per node, #3 = level
    if={level()>0}{
      content/.pgfmath={int(#1 + 1 + (n() - 1) * aryTree(level()))},
      ary Tree node
    }{ary Tree calc={#2}{#3}},
    if/.expanded={level()<#3}{
      repeat={#2}{
        append={[,ary Tree={\forestove{content}}{#2}{#3}]}}}{}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} setup ary Tree nodes={00}{}
[,ary Tree={0}{2}{3}, ary Tree root]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest} setup ary Tree nodes={00}{inner ysep=+2pt}, 
               ary Tree node/.append style={s sep=+0pt}
[,ary Tree={0}{3}{3}, ary Tree root]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest} setup ary Tree nodes={00}{inner ysep=+2pt},
               ary Tree node/.append style={s sep=+0pt},
               delay={for tree={calign=first}}
[,ary Tree={0}{4}{2}, ary Tree root]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

[`ary Tree={0}{4}{4}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8csqJ.png)

Comment: Instead of `delay` and adding the `s sep` option to `ary Tree node`, it is better to use for example `before packing={for tree={calign=first, s sep=+0pt}}`.

Comment: Very nice ;) and some filler.