# A tree with complicated nodes as each child in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Trying to make a tree where each child is a set of nodes that can be created separately and then linked somehow in to different positions in a tree.

Lets say I have a group of nodes and edges such as

```
\node (1) at (0,1) {1};
\node (2) at (0,2) {2};
\draw(->, bend left=90, dotted) (1.north) -- (2.north);
```

I have looked at trees and it seems that each child can only be one node. I would like to be able to use, for example, the three above commands and treat them as one child (and have the relative coordinates kept within a child). Perhaps it is possible to do this with a macro(?) although I can't find any examples/literature on it.

For example, something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node {root} 
    child {\node (1) at (0,0) {A}; \node (1) at (0,0) {B}};
    child {\node (1) at (0,0) {C}; \node (1) at (0,0) {D} 
      child {\node (1) at (0,0) {C};} 
      child {\node (1) at (0,0) {D};} 
    }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post code that compiles, preferably as a minimal working example including `\documentclass` and loading the necessary packages.  As it stands your final example does not produce a valid tree: for example `node` should be used instead of `\node` except at the root.

Comment: You can try with `pics` (pgfmanual, section 18) but I'm not sure about their use in `trees`.

Comment: @Andrew Swann I know it doesn't compile; I am suggesting that as an example of how I would like to have several nodes within one child.

Comment: James, the point that Andrew Swann was making is that it is much better to post complete code that compiles so that people have something to work from. This saves a lot of time for everyone, and it makes it much more likely that people will try and help.

Comment: relevant? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136855/how-to-draw-search-space-tree-in-a-dynamic-manner

Comment: @Andrew I understand this. If I had code that compiled I would post it, but I also wouldn't be asking for help.

Comment: @seteropere Thanks. I looked at the forest environment and it didn't look like it did what I wanted, although I may be wrong.

Comment: Even if it is not good practice, you can put `\tikz...;` commands inside the contents of a node...is this what you want? A node in the tree can contain arbitrary tikz code?

Comment: @James Even if you cannot make it compile, you surely can make it closer to being compilable. For example, you presumably don't need help to know that it won't compile with `\documentclass`, relevant `\usepackage` and `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you after, but you can certainly write subtrees as macros, which should start with a `child`.  Alternatively you can use `pics`.  I give three examples:

[image: Sample output level]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mysubtree}[2]{child {node {#1}} 
      child {node {#2}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}] 
  \node (R) {root} 
  child {node  {A}
  child {node  {B}}}
  child {node {C} \mysubtree DE}
  child {node {F} \mysubtree GH}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can add quite complicated code to these macros:

[image: Sample coloured output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mysubtree}[3]{child {node[red] {#1}
      child {node[draw] {#2}} 
      child[edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor)
        edge [bend left] (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)}]
        {node[circle,fill=green] {#3} }}} 


\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node {root} 
  child {node  {A}
   child {node  {B}
    \mysubtree CDE
    \mysubtree FGH}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Finally using `pics` may be closest to what you ask.  You can simply place a `pic` instead of a `node` but there is an anchoring problem for the edges, see the right most node below.  Instead place these together with a dummy node that takes is a blank rectangle of appropriate size:

[image: Sample pic output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{ mynode/.pic={
  \node (1) at (-0.25,0) {1};
  \node (2) at (0.25,0) {2};
  \draw[->, bend left=90, dotted] (1.north) -- (2.north);
  },
  mypic/.style={rectangle,minimum size=4ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (R) {root} 
  child {node  {A}
  child {node  {B}}}
  child { node[mypic] {} pic {mynode} }
  child { node[mypic] {} pic {mynode} }
  child { pic {mynode} }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. The `pics` solution is perfect, thanks.